# MySQL SELECT all rows between date time with interval

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my sql table called `loggedTime` which is a `datetime` field and I want to select between two dates `startDate` and `endDate` along with the `interval` may be 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hour etc. I tried to write the SQL query but it says You have syntax error next interval, I am not sure what wrong with my query. If I remove INTERVAL 5 MINUTE my query works fine but I want to pass the Interval along with the date so it will select all rows between two dates and also with interval

Here is SQL

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE loggedTime BETWEEN '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-03' INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: select query, 5 minute increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403039/mysql-select-query-5-minute-increment)

Comment: What do you mean with the interval maybe 5 minutes,..? In your query you are using date, not time. With all respect, I think you have miss-understood INTERVAL usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any unique consecutively increasing column like `id`, then you can use an `INNER JOIN` as done followingly:

```
SELECT *
FROM       mytable a
INNER JOIN mytable b 
        ON a.ID = b.ID + 1
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, a.timestamp, b.timestamp) = 5;
```

If you do not have that column in your table then use this code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT mt.*,
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, @prevTS, `loggedTime`) AS timeinterval,
             @prevTS:=mt.`loggedTime`
      FROM mytable mt, 
           (SELECT @prevTS := (SELECT MIN(`loggedTime`) 
                               FROM yourTable)) vars
      ORDER BY ID)subquery_alias
WHERE loggedTime BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-03' 
  AND timeinterval = 5
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014760/mysql-calculate-time-difference-between-timestamps-in-same-field/18015576#18015576) as reference too.

Comment: Your answer does not have anything to do with INTERVAL keyword, which clearly is what questioner wants to read about.

Comment: @Syed Ahmed, it works fine but the only issue is that BETWEEN ending date isn't getting results from todays date i.e. 2021-06-22 but if I use 2021-06-23 it works can you help me with that?